# Is it possible to create variable in parent class, that would initialized once per derrived type?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm using IDataErrorInfo interface to validate my entities. As long as validation logic is reading metadata from attributes, it is the same for all entities, so I've created class

```
public class DataErrorInfo : IDataErrorInfo
```

And all entities are derriving from it. Thing is, that I wish to cache reflection info for derived classes to speed up validation, so every entity type should initialize this cache once per running application.

I was thinking to use `static readonly` field, but found out, that it is initialized with first used entity type's reflection info, so if there's entity A and entity B, and entity A is accessed first, entity B will have entity A reflection cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a generic class if you have a static it's for the closed generic type you can leverage this.
Define your base class as a generic (with a somewhat odd looking but valid constraint)

```
public class DataErrorInfo<T> : IDataErrorInfo where T : DataErrorInfo<T>{
...
}
```

you then define your derived class like this (notice that the derived class itself is passed as T to the base generic type)

```
public class EntityClass : DataErrorInfo<EntityClass>{
...
}
```

that way any static is scoped to the derived class not the parent class as long as you don't do as below

```
public class AnotherEntityClass : DataErrorInfo<EntityClass>{
...
}
```

Comment: `DataErrorInfo<T> where T : DataErrorInfo<T>`? Are you sure there is some `T` for which this would hold?

Comment: @Vlad yes it will hold for all classes that derives from DataErrorInfo<T>

Comment: But you need to find a `T` first, right? For the very first derived class. (Maybe you can make an example?)

Comment: @vlad nope :) take a look at the example above.

Comment: Why the dv? The solution provides a mechanism for solving OPs problem.

Comment: Very clever indeed :)...but what would happen if you derive from say EntityClass...If this is not permitted then I think it is better to mention it in the question itself...If it is permitted and the reflection cache needs to be tied to the derivation of EntityClass then this solution will fail. In that case it would be better to go with @Yuck solution.

Comment: Also using generics like this, would mean that an object variable of exact type will always be required to hold references of derived types negating one of the major advantages of using inheritance.

Comment: @Amit the worst case is that you will have one more level in the inheritance chain. Aside from that you can use the types exactly as you would otherwise have

Comment: Ahh...my bad...any way I was thinking only from perspective of DataErrorInfo. Didn't notice DataErrorInfo<T> derives from IDataErrorInfo :) Also DataErrorInfo<T> can itself be derived from DataErrorInfo. Should have thought more before the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Dictionary<Type, DataErrorInfo>` implemented as a [Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

The Singleton pattern enforces that only one `Dictionary` exists in memory.  The `Dictionary` itself will enforce the constraint that each type gets one entry as a `Key`.  Your `Value` is going to be whatever reflection info you want cached.  In this case it looks like that's `DataErrorInfo`.

Comment: A static read-only dictionary in the base class will be as helpful as a singleton. DataErrorInfo class can in its constructor populate the dictionary by using 'GetType()' as the key. Assuming that obtaining 'reflection cache' is an expensive process, by using '!_reflectionDict.ContainsKey(GetType())' (O(1) complexity) the expensive reflection cache process can be performed exactly once per derived type. Even in case of multi-level inheritance, dictionary will always have one reflection cache per derived type.